# pyodbc: How to prevent Communication link failure, ConnectionWrite, and ConnectionRead errors?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to connect to my SQL server. My scripts run most of the times as expected but sometimes I get either of these 3 errors when the script is executing a command with the SQL database:

> 1. pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>      Driver]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
> 2. pyodbc.Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>      Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()). (10054)
>      (SQLExecDirectW)')
> 3. pyodbc.Error: ('01000', '[01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>      Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionRead (recv()). (10054) (SQLExecDirectW)')

What can I do to prevent this?

Edit:
Actual commands in my script are really very basic ones so I didn't mention it in my original post.

```
import pyodbc
connectionString1 = 'x'
connection1 = pyodbc.connect(connectionString1)
cursor1 = connection1.cursor()
query1 = '''
            SELECT/UPDATE ...
            '''
cursor1.execute(query1)
res = cursor1.fetchall()
# do some operations using res
connection1.commit()
```

Comment: We may need to see the actual command(s).

Comment: @Parfait please check the edited post

Comment: You are not getting those errors because of simple `SELECT` statements. It's your environment like db configurations, TCP ports, network. I advise asking this on [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:**

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I have the same problem today because the length of the field is not enough relative to the length of the data. Lengthening the length of the field will solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Lengthening the length of the field"?

Comment: Increase the field length

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to your connectionString1 and it should work

"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
"Auto_Commit=true;"