# Connection Leak in Azure WebApp Using Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Flask App running on an Ubuntu WebApp on Azure. Every morning my queries to the app fail with the below error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM to query my Azure SQL Server Instance. I believe that my connections are becoming stale for the following reasons.

1. It happens every morning after no one uses the app
2. After X many failed returns, it starts working, until the next morning.

However to make things more weird, when I check `sys.dm_exec_sessions` on the sql server, it does not show any active connections (outside of the one I'm executing to check).

In addition, when I run the dockerized app on my local and connect to the DB I get no such error.

If anyone has had a similar issue I'd love some insights, or at least a recommendation on where to drill down.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html

This link helped me, but the solution is only for Windows Apps, not Linux.

Comment: This may help https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#pool-disconnects

Comment: You can check the similar issues [pyodbc: How to prevent Communication link failure, ConnectionWrite, and ConnectionRead errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68329142/15969115), [SQLSTATE 08S01: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server TCP Provider](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/835) and https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @snakecharmerb:

The application was in-fact holding on to a pool of dead connections, setting pool_recycle to a greater time solved the issue.

```
engine = create_engine(
        key, echo=False, future=True,
        echo_pool=True,
        #  connection pool will log informational output such as when connections are invalidated.
        pool_recycle=3600
        #  causes the pool to recycle connections after the given number of seconds has passed.
    )
```